# Plot EMa only for specific timeframes

Tags: pine-script

I am using Pinescript Version 3 and am struggling to hide an ema on certain timeframes.  i dont want to show the ema on any timeframe lower than 1hr.  Teh below code shows the ema on all timeframes.

Code are as follow:

```
emaLength = not isintraday ? 8 :
     (interval == 15) ? 8 :
     (interval >= 60) ? 8 :
     8

emaValue = ema(priceData, emaLength)

plot(series=emaValue, color=orange, linewidth=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `na` to `plot()` when you don't want anything plotted. You also need a condition that checks that the current timeframe is <= 60 minutes and return `na` if that is true. Here's how it can be done:

```
emaLength = 8
drawEMA = not (isintraday and interval <= 60)
emaValue = ema(priceData, emaLength)

plot(series=drawEMA ? emaValue : na, color=orange, linewidth=3)
```